# What's the difference between ArrayBuffer.addOne and ArrayBuffer.append?

Tags: scala, append, arraybuffer, scala-2.13

2.13.3 API says:

```
def addOne(elem: A): ArrayBuffer.this.type
```

*Adds a single element to this array buffer.*

```
final def append(elem: A): ArrayBuffer.this.type
```

*Appends the given elements to this buffer.*

They seem to do the exact same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same thing. `ArrayBuffer` is a descendent of `Buffer`, which defines `append`:

```
@`inline` final def append(elem: A): this.type = addOne(elem)
```

`addOne` is implemented in `ArrayBuffer` as part of its implementation towards `Growable`.

See: [Buffer.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/9468b9abcda6955688804194c02fe11db8c78a38/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/Buffer.scala#L43).